# Are chart patterns for securities self-fulfilling prophesies?

Tags: stocks, securities

I have been reading about various common chart patterns, such as head and shoulders etc, and it seems like these patterns could be self-fulfilling prophesies since many investors are aware of them and react in the same way when a pattern emerges. Are chart patterns for securities self fulfilling prophesies?

Comment: Most such trading "strategies" are just mumbo jumbo --- but the fact that many (though not all) people follow them means the pattern of trades does what the mumbo jumbo predicts. Whether it makes money (or sense) or not is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @PeterK. - so "mumbo jumbo" means it is something you don't understand, but not something no one understands. So maybe if you don't understand something you should keep your thoughts to yourself - as you are really not helping anyone else.

Comment: @Victor And if you think you understand mumbo-jumbo you should also keep your thoughts to yourself. :-)

Comment: @PeterK. - not my problem if you are confused. If I am confused about something I try to learn about it not ridicule it.

Comment: I do not know of any evidence that proves or disproves the causality of stock patterns, so I do not think this question can be answered one way or the other (outside of opinions).

Comment: @DStanley - I think there are enough people who follow technical analysis, and volumes of books on the topic, that we shouldn't dismiss it here. I view it as the financial version of a religion other than my own. I don't follow it, but I don't disrespect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a combination of both. Patterns like "head & shoulders" do have a valid psychological explanation behind them. To take it apart, it's essentially a failure of a new high (the last "shoulder") in which the buyers are now nervous after a long uptrend, now when it breaches the recent bottom, there is a lot of room for it to go down and the most anxious long participants  take profit.

Not every pattern has an explanation and some of those could be just "mumbo jumbo" as the psychological explanations are weak at best. But anything related to the markets is about likelihood and no matter how well the pattern is defined, if a very big market participant wants to do something else, the patterns fail.

Answer (score 1):

Many patterns and other signals in technical trading are based on the psychology of the markets.

You mentioned a head and shoulders as an example, well where and why do patterns such as head and shoulders, double tops and triple tops occur.

They occur at a market top. The price had recently hit a high point and then reversed back down. After a certain move down the price starts looking cheap so new buyers come in and push the price back up. As the price starts to reach the previous high the number of buyers dry up as the price is starting to look expensive again. Some short to medium term traders will start to take profits and short sellers will start to enter the market. This starts to drive the price back down just as the previous high is reached again. Unless there is some new good news that will push the price above the ceiling of the previous high, prices will usually retract around that point.

The same thing happens in reverse with double bottoms, triple bottoms and reverse head and shoulders.

It is well and good to try to follow certain patterns by thinking that others will also follow them, but it is better to try to understand why these patterns are happing in the first place. It is also important to understand that if you are going to try to trade a pattern you will need to have your risk management in place. Make sure you place a stop loss at an appropriate place, in case the pattern fails.

A good point to start with understanding patterns is to read about the psychology of the markets.